# Baire category and the existence of very continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, baire-category

I want to prove the existence of a $f:C([0,1])\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{h\to0}\sup|h|^{-\alpha}|f(x+h)-f(x)|\to \infty$$
for all $x\in [0,1]$. Where $\alpha > 0$.

I was given the hint that I should consider the sets $E_m$ consisting of those $f ∈ C([0, 1])$ for which
there exists an $x ∈ [0, 1]$ with $|f(x + h) − f(x)| \le m|h|^
α$ for all $x + h ∈ [0, 1]$. And then applying some version of Baire category. I am really flummoxed by this however as since we only know what these $f$ do at a single $x\in [0,1]$ it is really difficult to see how we can combine this to get a result that holds at all $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: $\alpha$ being?

Comment: You probably also want $f$ nonconstant...

Comment: Sorry, I am so stupid. I meant that the limit is $\infty$ >:(

Comment: If you can read German, then you can read the original proof of this result, due to Auerbach and Banach in 1931: [*Über die Höldersche bedingung*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm3/sm3111.pdf) [**Studia Mathematica** 3 (1931), pp. 180-184] Note that they prove a stronger result in which $h^{\alpha}$ is replaced by an arbitrary modulus of continuity function ${\omega}(h).$

Answer (score 2):

Outline: First show that every $E_m$ is closed and nowhere dense. As $C([0,1])$ is a complete metric space, the Baire category theorem implies that there must be $f \in C([0,1])$ such that $f \notin E_m$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$.